# Print actual characters instead of NCR's

Tags: xml, perl, character-encoding, xml-libxml

I'd like to print an XML document without reducing all of the unicode containing in it to ugly NCRs. Here's a sample:

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->load_xml(string => '<xml>ＦＵＬＬ ＷＩＤＴＨ</xml>');
print $doc->toString();
```

This prints the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>&#xFF26;&#xFF35;&#xFF2C;&#xFF2C; &#xFF37;&#xFF29;&#xFF24;&#xFF34;&#xFF28;</xml>
```

Very, very ugly and difficult to read (unless viewed in a browser or something).

How can I get the document to print real characters, and to have a utf-8 (or whatever other encoding) declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object type returned by XML::LibXML::Parser is XML::LibXML::Document, which has a `setEncoding` method:

```
$doc->setEncoding('utf-8');
```

Now the script prints this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>ＦＵＬＬ ＷＩＤＴＨ</xml>
```

Comment: Isn't XML's default encoding is UTF-8? weird.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why it's like that. It might be different if it had a utf-8 encoding declaration in the original parsed string.